# is onStop() always called once onPause() is called

Tags: android

Is it possible that onPause() is called, and then immediately after that, onResume() is called? In other words, does the activity always has to go through onStop(), onStart() and then onResume() after its onPause() is called?

The activity lifecycle document says it is possible, but what would be the user actions to trigger that? Can anyone create an activity JUnit test to demonstrate that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is common for `onPause()` -> `onResume()` -> `onPause()` -> `onResume()` cycle to occur.

See the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) docs.

If an `Activity` is totally obscured (by another `Activity` for example) it will likely be stopped but if it is only partly obscured by another `Activity` (set with a dialog theme, for example), then it will simply be paused and then resumed when the 'popup' `Activity` is closed.

Comment: In my experiments, not even onPause() is called for popup dialogs. I can only observe the desired behavior (onPause called but onStop not called) by clicking the power-off button, but I haven't tested it on a real device yet.

Comment: @dacongy : Actually you may be right for things like `AlertDialog` popups not causing `onPause()` to be called. Thinking about it, I have several 'popups' which are actually `Activity` classes created with a dialog 'theme'. They effectively look like popups but don't cover the whole screen - the result is that `onPause()` IS called but because they don't completely obscure the underlying `Activity`, it only gets paused and doesn't go to the `onStop()` stage.

Comment: No, onPause() is NOT called. I have put logcat prints inside callback methods, and nothing is printed about onPause() when dialogs pop up.

Comment: I tested on a real device, and pressing the power button can achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: @dacongy : All my `Activity` classes extend a base `Activity` which I created and each of the `onXXXX` methods log that they are being called. I can confirm absolutely that when one of my dialog themed `Activities` partially covers another `Activity` the `onPause()` method of that `Activity` IS definitely called. Perhaps this is a variation on different Android versions and device implementations.

Comment: OK, now I see the difference. The "dialogs" I'm talking about are actually context menus as defined in onCreateContextMenu(), while the dialogs you are seeing are actually activities that look like dialogs.

Comment: @dacongy : Yes, that would make sense. Although things like `AlertDialog` or `ContextMenu` don't inherit directly from `View` they are still just very much a 'view holder' owned by the current `Activity` and as such won't interfere with it. Using a dialog-themed `Activity`, however, does trigger a change in the underlying `Activity's` lifecycle putting it into a paused state but, because it is still partially visible, it doesn't go to a stopped state. As such, closing the `Activity` 'dialog' simply moves the underlying `Activity` from paused to resumed.

Answer (score 5):

If `Activity` hasn't been fully obscured by another `Activity` then `onStop` won't be called

Answer (score 0):

image [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) tell every thing nicely

Activity can go to `onResume` directly after `onPause`.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking this question. What would be the actions to trigger the state transition *directly* from onPause() to onResume()?

Comment: here situation only belongs to `OS`. As far I know we can not do much about it.

Comment: What does it mean to "belong to OS"?