# How to pause an activity on the emulator without stoping it

Tags: android, onpause, android-homebutton

My question is almost similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549406/is-onstop-always-called-once-onpause-is-called). In my app when I press the home button my app is stopped and not only paused. After reading the answers in the question (given in the link) I realized that onPause and onStop is indeed called after pressing the home button. So my question is how do I pause my activity on the emulator( there is no lock screen button) without stopping it or doing it programmitically.My logcat details are :

```
  06-24 05:43:29.011: D/My(1689): OnCreate
  06-24 05:43:29.011: D/My(1689): OnResume
  06-24 05:43:34.251: D/Sng[0](1689): /storage/sdcard/Music/05.Only you.mp3
  06-24 05:43:34.771: E/MediaPlayer(1689): Should have subtitle controller already set
  06-24 05:43:41.691: D/My(1689): OnPause
  06-24 05:43:48.081: D/My(1689): OnStop
```

Comment: @Strider. That is a good link but i am trying to avoid doing it programmitically. My application is a mediaplayer sort of activity which on pausing will continue to play until stopped.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I deleted it, but you already checked it XD, srry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity will be paused, for example, when `dialog` will appear.
From Android Dev:

When the system calls `onPause()` for your activity, it technically means your activity is still partially visible

Comment: How can i simulate that on my emulator >

Comment: @SouravKanta You want that, just onPause() call?

Comment: Yeah I just want to pause my application and i prefer not to do it programitically

Comment: @SouravKanta You can click button to show stack of all open apps. In nexus 5, right button(square)

Comment: Igor but the emulator doesnt have that button. I am trying to write a mediaplayer app. How do the apps that we install in our mobile continue to play even after we play after the home button is pressed.Do they continue even when onStop is called.

Comment: All emulators have button recent apps(from android studio or genymotion).  I tried it, and only onPause() method was called

Answer (score 0):

create a alertdialog in your activity when in onResume()(or press a button)

```
    // 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
           .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

    // 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show()
```